# cakephp function calling

Tags: cakephp, function, request

whats the use of calling a cakephp function 
http://localhost/project/controller/method.hello

so whats hello?
but it requires views/method/hello/method.ctp...

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are some errors in your description.A typical CAKEPHP url should something like:

`webroot/controller/method/argument`

and a method must have a view file.See [typical request of cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/view/21/A-Typical-CakePHP-Request)

Answer (score 2):

As SpawnCxy noticed, maybe you did not understand well the request "philosophy".

Anyway, using routes you can define your own, but the default is

```
/:controller:/:function:[/:arguments:]
```

remember that you can also use [Named Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/541/Named-parameters)